# Variance of an Iterative Normally Distrubuted Function

Tags: probability

What is the variance of the following function??

$f(x_n)=f(x_{n-1})(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m)) $

Hence, $f(x_n)=f(x_0)\prod_1^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m)) $

Where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ is i.i.d $\lor n$ and $1\leq n\leq m$ and $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are positive constants. Let $f(x_0)=1$ in this example

Here is as far as I have gotten:

In order for me to calculate the variance, I need to calculate the expectations of $f(x_n)$. My problem is the function is geometric not linear. So, I tried logging the function, to break the terms up into linear pieces.

So $ln(f(x_n))=lnf(x_0)+\sum_1^n ln(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_n\sqrt (1/m))$

But since the log function is concave, I would somehow have to introduce Jensen's Inequality.
The other way I tried doing it is by taking the expectation at each $n$ and try to see a pattern,

$E(f(x_1))=f(x_0)+f(x_0)\alpha (1/m)+0=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))    $

$E(f(x_2))=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))+f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))\alpha (1/m)+0=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))^2$

...
Which then I would surmise,
$E(f(x_n))=f(x_0)(1+\alpha (1/m))^n$
Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your indices and variables are correct?

$$E[f(x_n)] = E[f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_\color{red}{i}\sqrt {1/m})] $$

$$ = f(x_0)E[\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_i\sqrt {1/m})] $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^nE[(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_i\sqrt {1/m})] $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(E[1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta\epsilon_i\sqrt {1/m}]) $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(E[1]+E[\alpha (1/m)]+E[\beta\epsilon_i\sqrt {1/m}]) $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta \sqrt {1/m} E[\epsilon_i]) $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\alpha (1/m)+\beta \sqrt {1/m} (0)) $$

$$ = f(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\alpha (1/m)) $$

$$ = f(x_0) (1+\alpha (1/m))^n $$

I'm not quite sure the above holds if we have n instead of i considering $E[X^n] \ne (E[X])^n$